# Is there a clean way to cancel an OkHttp 3 request when RxJava 2 Disposable is disposed?

Tags: java, android, rx-java2, okhttp

So I've been trying to find a clean way of solving this issue for a while. Here's REST API class:

```
public class RestClient {

    private final IJsonParser jsonParser;
    private IServerUtils serverUtils;
    private String baseApiUrl;
    private OkHttpClient okHttpClient;

    @Inject
    public RestClient(OkHttpClient okHttpClient, IJsonParser jsonParser, IServerUtils serverUtils, @Named("baseApiUrl") String baseApiUrl) {
        this.okHttpClient = okHttpClient;
        this.jsonParser = jsonParser;
        this.serverUtils = serverUtils;
        this.baseApiUrl = baseApiUrl;
    }

    public Single<String> get(String route) {
        if (serverUtils.isThereInternetConnection()) {
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .get()
                    .url(baseApiUrl + route)
                    .build();
            final Call call = okHttpClient.newCall(request);
            return Single.create(emitter -> {
                execute(call, emitter);
            });
        } else {
            return Single.error(new NetworkException());
        }
    }

    public Single<String> post(String route, RequestBody requestBody) {
        if (serverUtils.isThereInternetConnection()) {
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .post(requestBody)
                    .url(baseApiUrl + route)
                    .build();
            final Call call = okHttpClient.newCall(request);
            return Single.create(emitter -> execute(call, emitter));
        } else {
            return Single.error(new NetworkException());
        }
    }

    public Single<String> postNoCache(String route, RequestBody requestBody) {
        if (serverUtils.isThereInternetConnection()) {
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .post(requestBody)
                    .url(baseApiUrl + route)
                    .cacheControl(CacheControl.FORCE_NETWORK)
                    .build();
            final Call call = okHttpClient.newCall(request);
            return Single.create(emitter -> execute(call, emitter));
        } else {
            return Single.error(new NetworkException());
        }
    }

    Response postRaw(String route, RequestBody requestBody) throws IOException {
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .post(requestBody)
                .url(baseApiUrl + route)
                .build();

        return okHttpClient.newCall(request).execute();
    }

    public RequestBody convertHashMapToRequestBody(HashMap<String, String> params) {
        FormBody.Builder builder = new FormBody.Builder();
        for (String key : params.keySet()) {
            builder.add(key, params.get(key));
        }
        return builder.build();
    }

    private void execute(Call call, SingleEmitter<String> emitter) throws IOException {
        try {
            Response response = call.execute();
            String responseJson = response.body().string();
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                emitter.onSuccess(responseJson);
            } else {
                handleErrors(emitter, response, responseJson);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedIOException e) {
         // This is my issue.
        }

    }

    private void handleErrors(SingleEmitter<String> emitter, Response response, String responseJson) {
        if (response.code() == 500 && responseJson != null) {
            ApiError error = jsonParser.parseApiError(responseJson);
            emitter.onError(new ApiException(error.getErrorMsg(), error.getError(), error.getUri()));
        } else {
            emitter.onError(new NetworkException("timeout"));
        }
    }
```

So in my execute() method I'd like to somehow maybe get some sort of callback when my upstream observer is destroyed, so I can cancel my network request. Currently what seems to happen is the thread that the Single is running on gets an interrupt, which throws an Exception, I'm not sure if this stops execution though. Is there a clean way of doing that? The only thing I've seen that you can do is the emitter.isDisposed(), which I can't see a normal usecase, since everything is synchronous in here and by the time I check that value it's most likely too late.

any help with this would be greatly appreciated.